# Flatten a Parent/Child hierarchy

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to understand a concept here:

From an object structure like

```
class Parent
{
    public string ParentID { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; } 
}

class Child
{
   public string ChildID { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming a fully populated parent object, I would like to use Linq to Xml to obtain the following Xml output:

```
<Mappings>
   <Mapping ID='ParentID1' ChildID='ChildID1'>
   <Mapping ID='ParentID1' ChildID='ChildID2'>
</Mappings>
```

How do I unwind the original object nested to obtain this mapping list?

**EDIT**

Example with a parent such as :

```
ParentID = 'Parent1', Children = new [] { "Child1", "Child2", "Child3" }
```

I am expecting 3 mappings :

```
<Mapping ID='Parent1' ChildID='Child1' />
<Mapping ID='Parent1' ChildID='Child2' />
<Mapping ID='Parent1' ChildID='Child3' />
```

Comment: `Assuming a fully populated parent object`, How about posting it?

Comment: I don't understand what you are hoping to see. This is a conceptual question. The actual string literals that will populate the ParentID and ChildID values are inconsequential to the solution. As such, there is nothing to post.

Comment: What have you tried so far in your attempts to generate this type of file?  What problems, specifically, are you having with that implementation?

Comment: I don't understand how to effectively build it in the linq-to-xml syntax because when creating the first "Mapping" XElement I need a ChildID value for each entry, but I don't know how to express it in the syntax.

Comment: @ L.B. Please spare me your brazen one liners. If you don't want to help please move on. Otherwise tell me exactly what you need because I don't understand where you're coming from. I'm certainly not interested in providing you a medium to vent your daily frustrations.

Comment: Why are people down voting !?

Comment: It appears the genius that edited the title of this question managed to remove a huge part of the context, that is that I would like a solution in linq-to-xml syntax. One solution would have sufficed as a sample input and output was provided. This being too broad is just lunacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

The following code will flatten the hierarchy :

```
var list = new List<Parent>
{
    new Parent
    {
        ParentID = "parentID1",
        Children = new List<Child> {new Child {ChildID = "childID1"}, new Child {ChildID = "childID2"}}
    },
    new Parent
    {
        ParentID = "parentID2",
        Children = new List<Child> {new Child {ChildID = "childID3"}, new Child {ChildID = "childID4"}}
    }
};

IEnumerable<XElement> list1 = (from parent in list
    from child in parent.Children
    select
        new XElement("Mapping", new XAttribute("ID", parent.ParentID),
            new XAttribute("ChildID", child.ChildID)));

string @join = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list1);
```

Output :

```
<Mapping ID="parentID1" ChildID="childID1" />
<Mapping ID="parentID1" ChildID="childID2" />
<Mapping ID="parentID2" ChildID="childID3" />
<Mapping ID="parentID2" ChildID="childID4" />
```

---

Here's an example on how to achieve it :

Note : this won't work, it will generate an exception saying 'Duplicate attribute'

```
List<Parent> list = new List<Parent>
{
    new Parent() {ParentID = "parentID1", Children = new List<Child>() {new Child() {ChildID = "childID1"},new Child() {ChildID = "childID2"}}},
    new Parent() {ParentID = "parentID2", Children = new List<Child>() {new Child() {ChildID = "childID3"},new Child() {ChildID = "childID4"}}}
    };
IEnumerable<string> enumerable = xElements.Select(s => s.ToString());


IEnumerable<XElement> xElements = list.Select(s => new XElement("Mapping", new XAttribute("ID", s.ParentID), s.Children.Select(t => new XAttribute("ChildID", t.ChildID))));
IEnumerable<string> enumerable = xElements.Select(s => s.ToString());
var @join = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, enumerable);
```

This one will because it will use the overload of `Select` that uses the index of the current object :

```
var list = new List<Parent>
{
    new Parent
    {
        ParentID = "parentID1",
        Children = new List<Child> {new Child {ChildID = "childID1"}, new Child {ChildID = "childID2"}}
    },
    new Parent
    {
        ParentID = "parentID2",
        Children = new List<Child> {new Child {ChildID = "childID3"}, new Child {ChildID = "childID4"}}
    }
};

IEnumerable<XElement> xElements =
    list.Select(
        s =>
            new XElement("Mapping", new XAttribute("ID", s.ParentID),
                s.Children.Select((t, u) => new XAttribute(string.Format("ChildID_{0}", u), t.ChildID))));
var @join = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,xElements);
```

Result : not what you've been expecting, right ?

```
<Mapping ID="parentID1" ChildID_0="childID1" ChildID_1="childID2" />
<Mapping ID="parentID2" ChildID_0="childID3" ChildID_1="childID4" />
```

**Why I've used this overload ?**

Because parent has a list of childrens, while the first code would work with one children it would not with many of them.

**Conclusion :**

Not sure about what you're trying to achieve,

Why don't you just keep the structure of your objects as it is currently ?

Comment: I am trying to obtain the sample XML I posted, in essence a (ParentID, ChildID) mapping, from data organized in the objects above. Changing either the data structure or the XML format is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Okay but as I've explained in my answer keeping such structure won't work with multiple childrens or are you expecting many mappings to be generated such as Parent1 -> Child1, Parent1 -> Child2 as the output ?

Comment: Effectively flatten that hierarchy and get all rows: I included an example as an edit in original post.

Comment: Okay, take a look at my edit.

Comment: Ok, I get it, I should've started with a list query when building that segment. I was thinking I needed something similar like a CROSS-APPLY in SQL.

Comment: Glad it helped you :D Sorry but I can't really make any suggestions with SQL, my knowledge about it is non-existent. Just ignore these down-voters that don't even comment, your question was legitimate and deserved an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm here to figure something out not to win question of the month although I still don't get what happened.

Comment: It's just that some members of this community are very stressed,  IMO people at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/, http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ or http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ are on overall way cooler, they don't down-vote you right from the start; they try to understand by commenting first.